# Odata4j Not Found Exception

Tags: tomcat, odata, pom.xml, odata4j, entityset

I have created an OData producer with Tomcat by following this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/wiki/Tomcat).

However, when I go to the specified url at the tomcat server, I get the following error:

[image]

My pom.xml is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>eclipselink.example.jpa</groupId>
<artifactId>simple</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
        <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.odata4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata4j-examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```